# Fixed column as header (vertical header) and rest scrollable for table using Bootstrap2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabular, fixed-header-tables

I have tried various results but usually most of the places I got the horizontal fixed header.

But I am working with bootstrap 2 and want to make a table which have various dynamic columns so make fix first 3 columns to be used as vertical header for the table.

As I have given a tried to http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

I have given a try with:

```
$('#fixedTable').fixedHeaderTable({ footer: false, fixedColumns: 3 });
```

But its cloning the table with header vertically but not fixed as well as the UI breaks with pixels up and down with the original design.

But it's messing up the things with my table. Can anyone help on it?

Image for help:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7372h2ptm63bgqr/fixedHeaderVerticalBug.png]

I have a fiddle here: [jsfiddle.net/tysewu52](http://jsfiddle.net/tysewu52)

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed as vertical headers" ? I don't understand.

Comment: @azhpo Like this one http://jsfiddle.net/ANVNY/137/

Comment: Already saw a couple times and I can't really see what is the difference, the second fiddle you gave the difference I see is that it is with fixed width.

Comment: @azhpo There is a difference for the fiddele http://jsfiddle.net/ANVNY/137/ here when we scroll horizontally the vertical line is fixed that i want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66196/discussion-between-shivdhwaj-pandey-and-azhpo).